# how to load iscroll for dynamic div in android phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, iscroll

I have created application in android phonegap.In my application I have appended list in div dynamicallyloaded . how to add scrollbar  for dynamic div using iscroll.  I want to add scrollbar for dynamic div using iscroll.how to do this
My code is

Html:

```
         <div class="sidemenu" ></div>

       </div>
```

Style:

```
#scroller 
{
    top:90px;
    position:absolute; z-index:1;
    width:90%;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
li
{
list-style:none;
}
```

Script:

iscroll:

```
  var myScroll;
        function loaded() {
            myScroll = new iScroll('scroller', {
                useTransform: false,
                vScroll: true,
                onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) {
                    var target = e.target;
                    while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;

                    if (target.tagName != 'SELECT' && target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA')
                        e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setTimeout(function () { loaded(); }, 0), false);


       /** scrollbar for dynamic div*/ 
    function doIscrollRefresh () {  
        setTimeout(function () {
            myScroll.refresh();
        }, 0);

    }
```

dynamic div:
I have retrived value from localdatabase and appended into div dynamically

```
function list1(alphabet)
{
              doIscrollRefresh ();
             document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
             function onDeviceReady() 
             {

                    var db = window.openDatabase("createdb", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);

                    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB,successCB);

              } 
              function queryDB(tx) 
             {
                     var a=alphabet;
                     tx.executeSql("SELECT Textvalue FROM TextValue WHERE Textvalue LIKE '" + a + "%'",[], querySuccess, errorCB);
             }

             function querySuccess(tx,results)
              {
                   $(".sidemenu").append("<li>"+"<label style='background-color:#C1CDD9' >"+alphabet+ "</label>"+"</li>");
                   for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) 
                    {
                         $(".sidemenu").append("<li>"+"<a id='"+i+"'  href='#'>" +results.rows.item(i).Textvalue +  "</a>"+ "<hr/>"+ "</li>");
                    }
                    $(".sidemenu").append("<hr/>");
               }
          function errorCB(err) 
          {
                      alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
          }
          function successCB() 
          {
                 //alert("appended");   
          }
}
```

It show the error in logcat.the error is myScroll is undefined is not an object.
    Please tell me the solution.how to addthe scrollbar for dynamic div.please guide me.thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
.page {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 42px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
    border: 1px solid #F7C942;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-right-width: 0;
    background: #FADB4E;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FCEDA7), to(#FBEF7E));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FCEDA7, #FBEF7E);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#FCEDA7, #FBEF7E);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#FCEDA7, #FBEF7E);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#FCEDA7, #FBEF7E);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FCEDA7, #FBEF7E);
    z-index: 2;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 42px;
    bottom: 66px;
    padding-left: 4%;
    padding-right: 4%;
    width: 92%;
    border-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
    z-index: 1;
}

.scroller {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 64px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    border: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-right-width: 0;
    background: #EEE;
    color: #3E3E3E;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #DDD);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #DDD);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #DDD);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #DDD);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #DDD);
}

var Page = document.createElement('div');
    $(Page).attr('id', 'City');
    $(Page).addClass('page');

var Page = document.createElement('div');
    $(Page).attr('id', 'City');
    $(Page).addClass('page');

    //Header
    var Header = document.createElement('div');
    $(Header).addClass('header');
    $(Header).attr('align', 'center');

//Content
    var Content = document.createElement('div');
    $(Content).addClass('content');
    $(Content).attr('id', 'Wrapper');

    //Scroller
    var Scroller = document.createElement('div');
    $(Scroller).addClass('scroller');

Content.appendChild(Scroller);

    //Footer
    var Footer = document.createElement('div');
    $(Footer).addClass('footer');

    Page.appendChild(Header);
    Page.appendChild(Content);
    Page.appendChild(Footer);

    document.body.appendChild(Page);

    myScroll = new iScroll("Wrapper");

    setTimeout(function() {
        myScroll.refresh();
    }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

hi im not shure that will be the thing but if iscroll say that your iscroll is not define its because you call the loaded(); function at start and instance your dynamique code after that, so iscroll cant find your ellement !

i suggest you to callback the loaded function after your dynamique div is display and wrap

just recall the loaded(); function or use iScroll.refresh(); function when your ellement is already display .

```
  function querySuccess(tx,results)
          {
               $(".sidemenu").append("<li>"+"<label style='background-color:#C1CDD9' >"+alphabet+ "</label>"+"</li>");
               for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) 
                {
                     $(".sidemenu").append("<li>"+"<a id='"+i+"'  href='#'>" +results.rows.item(i).Textvalue +  "</a>"+ "<hr/>"+ "</li>");
                }
                $(".sidemenu").append("<hr/>");  
   ********************************************************************
      loaded();

/* or you can use*/

     myScroll.refresh();

 *********************************************************************
           }
```

the important thing to remind is to call or refresh the iscroll after your content is display and have style

Good luck !